# how to open multiple vlc interface (window) in xubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, vlc, lts

I am using xubuntu 14.04 lts. I notice new menu only allow to open one interface(window) of vlc. *I want to open two interface from menu at the same time for vlc*.

Is it possible to have that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open Vlc Media player. Choose preferences from the tools option in menu bar. Under Interface tab, disable both "*Use only one instance when started from file-manager*","*Allow only one instance*" options and click on save to save the changes.

Now you can be able to open two interfaces for vlc at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to open multiple instances of vlc **without unchecking** `Use only one instance when started from file manager` in `Preferences` is **open vlc from terminal**, that is open terminal and type `vlc` then press enter.

This way is good for those who sometimes need only one instance, sometimes need multiple instances, and don't want to open `Preferences` and check and uncheck `Use only one instance when started from file manager` many times.

ATTENTION. this way still need **unchecking** `Allow only one instance` in `Preferences`.