# vlc plays all videos in same window

Tags: 18.04, vlc, window

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

---

I want to play multiple videos at same time in VLC player, just like I used to do in Windows. But when I click to open new video it starts that video in the same video window itself.

---

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every new file to open in a new VLC window then follow these steps:

- Go to Tools > Preferences.
- Under Playlists and Instances, uncheck the option that says Use only **one instance when started from the file manager**.

Don't forget to click on the save button afterwards.

[image: VLC settings]

Now, every media file that you open from the file manager or any other place will open in a completely new VLC Media Player window.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459851/how-to-open-multiple-vlc-interface-window-in-xubuntu-14-04-lts). Go to "tools > Preferences > unmark 'use only one instance' next option ".

remember that you shall revert this change when your work is done.